# How do I stop a script running in UNIX?

Tags: php, unix, cron, terminal

I ran a php script, let's use "mytestscript.php" for example.

It will run continuously for a few hours. How can I stop it from the Terminal (UNIX) command line?

Comment: Programatically? If not this belongs on SuperUser...

Comment: What is SuperUser? And what are you considering to be 'programatically'?

Comment: [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/). StackOverflow is for programming questions. If you want to kill a script using any of the methods outlined in the answers below then you're not doing it programatically.. you're doing it as a user of the OS. If you're asking "How can I stop a running script USING PHP?" then that would be a programming question.

Answer (score 7):

Assuming it's running in the background, under your user id: use `ps` to find the command's PID. Then use `kill [PID]` to stop it. If `kill` by itself doesn't do the job, do `kill -9 [PID]`.

If it's running in the foreground, Ctrl-C (Control C) should stop it.

Read the documentation on the `ps` command and familiarize yourself with its options. It's a very useful command.

Comment: I like to use `kill -9` in any case, as a warning to other processes.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, here's the scoop on kill: despite its name, it's a command that sends _signals_ to other processes. The default signal is _TERM_, which tells the process to terminate. An application may catch this signal and do whatever it has to do to terminate in an orderly fashion. The using `kill -9` sends the KILL signal, which can't be caught (i.e.: the app has no chance to shut down orderly). So it's customary to try bare kill first before using -9. For a simple script that doesn't catch signals, it makes no difference.

Comment: I was joking, suggesting that I use the harsher command so that other processes will fear my wrath.

Answer (score 6):

You can try using `ps -e | grep php` to find all processes that have 'php' in their name. After that, you can do `kill <PID>`, replacing `<PID>` with the number the ps command gave you.

Answer (score 3):

If you want an automated solution try this -

1.Create a new shell script - `vi killer.sh`

2.Add the following

```
#!/bin/bash

while true
do
  sleep $1
  ps -ef | grep mytestscript.php | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -9  
done
```

3.Grant executable permissions `chmod +x killer.sh`

4.Execute your script as `nohup ./killer.sh <time to sleep before killing> &`

5.Leave it and go to the beach!

Answer (score 1):

You can always find the process id of the running process. "ps -ef | grep mytestscript.php". Look at the output and note down pid of the process. use kill pid to kill the process.